ReactJS hook vs utility function
Should we use utility functions in react or should everything be components and hooks?
I had this scenario:
Utility function for formatting money.
const formatMoney = (value) => value == null ? '' : '$' + value.toFixed(2)

This was used in more than 200 places. Everything was good, until the new requirement came. Now we were supposed to use dynamic currency, not only dollar.
So, the function formatMoney became dependent of the currently logged user in order to display his currency.
Few thigs that I could do:

add second parameter to the function and pass it everywhere manually
convert the function into hook/component, so it can get what it needs using hooks, since the logged user is kept in global provider.

The second variant was better, since the information that the function needs is a constant, won't be changed with something else. It will always come from the current user.
But both of those variants requires to manually refactor all the places that this function was used
The idea of a variable/function is to reuse some logic and it was doing it until it became dependent of something that it can't get itself, since functions can't call hooks.
I ended up with something like this
const useFormatMoney = (value) => {   // or a component
   const user = useUserContext()
   return value == null ? '' : user.currency + value.toFixed(2)
}

I wasn't able to do global replace, because now it has a react rules to follow, it should not be called conditionally, while before it could. After refactoring all those 200+ places, it made me rethink:
Every utility function one day can become dependent of something that is not able to get itself. But if I always use components/hooks they can always read things from providers and would not require to manually refactor all places that are used. So,
Is using utility functions a bad practice? Should we always use hooks/components?


Is using utility functions a bad practice?

No.
Even if you had named your original function useFormatMoney, it wouldn't have been a hook. It would have looked like a hook, and you might have used it like a hook, but it still would have been an ordinary function.
You could instead write a hook that returns a function
const useFormatMoney = () => {
   const user = useUserContext()
   return (value) => value == null ? '' : user.currency + value.toFixed(2)
}

This can be called unconditionally, and then the resulting function can be called conditionally. It is a much easier change, you can even keep the name formatMoney at the call sites.
N.b. a refactor is a change in code which keeps the observable behaviour the same, which is not the case here, the new requirement needs a change in behaviour.

The implementation does not matter here. The whole point was that it required me to make changes everywhere that this function was used. converting the function into hook. I created it to help me reuse logic, but at the end it still required me to manually change all 200+ places

@OktayYuzcan my point is that you can have an implementation that doesn't require you to make structural changes. When requirements change, you have to make some change to your code

maybe 200 places does not seem a lot to you, what if it was 1000? 2000? What is the problem if it is a custom hook and does not use any built-in hooks? It encapsulates the logic. It does not matter for the component what the hook does internally, it is a required for the component to threat it as a hook. This allows me to change the logic inside without telling the components that I changed something. I know that I have to make some changes, but I am using function in order to help me change something without telling the whole codebase I changed something. And at the end it can't do that

What you offer is no different than mine. Converting the function into hook. I still have to use it in all of those components in order to get the function it returns. It still requires me to make changes everywhere.

@OktayYuzcan yes, but those changes amount to changing an import, and calling the hook at the top level. It's a very mechanical change. The number of places doesn't really matter to me. If you have a collection of formatting functions, when the requirement comes in for some of them to depend on state, you might at that point wrap them all up in an object and return that from a hook, but your original design was sound for the requirements it had. Overengineering pre-emptively is also problematic.

I have a lot of functions and variables that begin being dependent of the global store. I am doing this regularly, moving around the whole codebase just to change things like this. If there is a problem that repeats itself, I wouldn't call it pre-emptively overengineering. I know that hooks have its own problems, but they can do things that regular functions can't. There are non standard solutions that could allow me to keep them as utility functions and still use some of the benefits of hooks, like mobx or preact-signals, but they might disappear when the compiler became standard.
